# Prevent flickering on drawing rectangular on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using "onmouseover" to draw rectangular on canvas, but somehow while drawing rectangular keep flickering. Here is the function which I am using to draw rectangular.

```
drawRect: (canvas, sX, sY, eX, eY) => {
        let context = getContext(canvas);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = "2";
        context.strokeStyle = "red";
        context.rect(sX, sY, eX, eY);
        context.stroke();
    }
```

Please assist me how I can prevent flickering of rectangular while drawing on canvas.

Regards,
Imran

Comment: Are you using requestAnimationFrame? It seems to be working fine in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qt67jp52/9/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would also be good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour